# python3.7にmatplotlibがインストール出来ません。

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

https://pypi.org/ から`matplotlib-3.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`をダウンロードしてコマンドプロンプトから

```
c:\Users\ﾕｰｻﾞｰ名\Downloads>pip install matplotlib-3.0.2-cp37-cp37m_amd.whl
```

と実行しても下記の様にエラー表示されてインストール出来ません。
対処方法が分かりましたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
Processing c:\users\m3170\downloads\matplotlib-3.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib==3.0.2)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020FF8DE9B70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。')': /simple/kiwisolver/
```

Comment: pipを最新に更新してから試すとか [Installing an official release](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-an-official-release)、予め依存関係にあるパッケージを別途ダウンロード・インストールしておくとか [Dependencies](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#dependencies) でしょうか。

Comment: `pip install matplotlib` と実行するのが標準的な方法だと存じますが、これではなく `.whl` ファイルを一回ダウンロードしているのにはなにか理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @PicoSushiさん、良くあるのが回答にあるようなproxy使用を知らなかったとか、使うのにユーザー登録・許可が必要かつ時間がかかるとかでしょうか。

Comment: pip install matplotlibをやってみましたがインストール出来ませんでした。pySirialの場合はダウンロードしてからインストールしてみたら上手くいきました。ユーザー登録も出来ていないので、そちらも調べてやってみます。

Answer (score 1):

proxy経由で接続する必要があるのではないでしょうか。下記のようにproxyオプションをつけて実行してみてください！

```
pip install --proxy http://[user:password@]proxyserver:port package
```

英語版だとこちらかと！
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy

Comment: 有難うございます。proxy経由という事が良く分かっていないのでよく調べてみます。

Comment: 出来ました、有難うございます。

Comment: よかったです！！上三角で投票していただけると嬉しいです！